# How should I stub a method globally using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I am working on a Rails application. I am trying to stub a method globally.

What I am doing is to stub it inside the RSpec configuration, on a `before(:suite)` block as follows:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    allow_any_instance_of(MyModel).to receive(:my_method).and_return(false)
  end
end
```

However, starting the test fails with the following error:

`` in `method_missing': undefined method `allow_any_instance_of' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup:0x00000008d6be08> (NoMethodError) ``

Any clue? How should I stub a method globally using RSpec?

P.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It probably is a context / initialization issue. Doing it in `config.before(:each)` should solve your problem.

Comment: `:each` is the default argument, so, you could leave it as just `config.before do`

Answer (score 17):

Do not stub methods in `before(:suite)` because stubs are cleared after each example, as stated in the [rspec-mocks README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/#use-beforeeach-not-beforeall):

> ### Use `before(:each)`, not `before(:all)`
>
> Stubs in `before(:all)` are not supported. The reason is that all stubs
>   and mocks get cleared out after each example, so any stub that is set
>   in `before(:all)` would work in the first example that happens to run in
>   that group, but not for any others.
>
> Instead of `before(:all)`, use `before(:each)`.

I think that's why `allow_any_instance_of` is not available in `before(:suite)` block, but is available in `before(:each)` block.

If the method is still missing, maybe you configured rspec-mocks to only allow `:should` syntax. `allow_any_instance_of` was introduced in RSpec 2.14 with all the new `:expect` syntax for message expectations.

Ensure that this syntax is enabled by inspecting the value of `RSpec::Mocks.configuration.syntax`. It is an array of the available syntaxes in rspec-mocks. The available syntaxes are `:expect` and `:should`.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = [:expect, :should]
  end
end
```

Once configured properly, you should be able to use `allow_any_instance_of`.

Comment: this is the correct response for when you are seeing this error `The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported.`

Answer (score 11):

I recently ran into a case where I needed to stub something in a `before(:all)` or `before(:context)` block, and found the solutions here to not work for my use case.

RSpec docs on [before() & after() hooks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) says that it's not supported:

> before and after hooks can be defined directly in the example groups they
>   should run in, or in a global RSpec.configure block.
>
> WARNING: Setting instance variables are not supported in before(:suite).
>
> **WARNING: Mocks are only supported in before(:example).**
>
> Note: the :example and :context scopes are also available as :each and
>   :all, respectively. Use whichever you prefer.

### Problem

I was making [a gem for writing a binary file format](https://github.com/trinitronx/lzop-file) which contained at unix epoch timestamp within it's binary header.  I wanted to write RSpec tests to check the output file header for correctness, and compare it to a test fixture binary reference file.  In order to create fast tests I needed to write the file out once before all the example group blocks would run.  In order to check the timestamp against the reference file, I needed to force `Time.now()` to return a constant value. This led me down the path of trying to stub `Time.now` to return my target value.

However, since `rspec/mocks` did not support stubbing within a `before(:all)` or `before(:context)` block it didn't work.  Writing the file `before(:each)` caused other strange problems.

Luckily, I stumbled across [issue #240 of rspec-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/240) which had the solution!

### Solution

Since January 9th 2014 ([rspec-mocks PR #519](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/pull/519)) RSpec now contains a method to work around this:

[**`RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope`**](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/3dcef6d4499e83cc64c970f5b17b68c9cc6e83ae)

### Example

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/mocks'

describe 'LZOP::File' do
  before(:all) {
    @expected_lzop_magic = [ 0x89, 0x4c, 0x5a, 0x4f, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a ]
    @uncompressed_file_data = "Hello World\n" * 100
    @filename = 'lzoptest.lzo'
    @test_fixture_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'fixtures', @filename + '.3')
    @lzop_test_fixture_file_data = File.open( @test_fixture_path, 'rb').read
    @tmp_filename = File.basename(@filename)
    @tmp_file_path = File.join( '', 'tmp', @tmp_filename)

    # Stub calls to Time.now() with our fake mtime value so the mtime_low test against our test fixture works
    # This is the mtime for when the original uncompressed test fixture file was created
    @time_now = Time.at(0x544abd86)
  }

  context 'when given a filename, no options and writing uncompressed test data' do

    describe 'the output binary file' do
      before(:all) {
        RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope do
          allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(@time_now)
          # puts "TIME IS: #{Time.now}"
          # puts "TIME IS: #{Time.now.to_i}"
          my_test_file = LZOP::File.new( @tmp_file_path )
          my_test_file.write( @uncompressed_file_data )
          @test_file_data = File.open( @tmp_file_path, 'rb').read
        end
      }

      it 'has the correct magic bits' do
        expect( @test_file_data[0..8].unpack('C*') ).to eq @expected_lzop_magic
      end

      ## [...SNIP...] (Other example blocks here)
      it 'has the original file mtime in LZO file header' do
        # puts "time_now= #{@time_now}"

        if @test_file_data[17..21].unpack('L>').first & LZOP::F_H_FILTER == 0
          mtime_low_start_byte=25
          mtime_low_end_byte=28
          mtime_high_start_byte=29
          mtime_high_end_byte=32
        else
          mtime_low_start_byte=29
          mtime_low_end_byte=32
          mtime_high_start_byte=33
          mtime_high_end_byte=36
        end
        # puts "start_byte: #{start_byte}"
        # puts "end_byte: #{end_byte}"
        # puts "mtime_low: #{@test_file_data[start_byte..end_byte].unpack('L>').first.to_s(16)}"
        # puts "test mtime: #{@lzop_test_fixture_file_data[start_byte..end_byte].unpack('L>').first.to_s(16)}"

        mtime_low = @test_file_data[mtime_low_start_byte..mtime_low_end_byte].unpack('L>').first
        mtime_high = @test_file_data[mtime_high_start_byte..mtime_high_end_byte].unpack('L>').first
        # The testing timestamp has no high bits, so this test should pass:
        expect(mtime_low).to eq @time_now.to_i
        expect(mtime_high).to eq 0

        expect(mtime_low).to eq @lzop_test_fixture_file_data[mtime_low_start_byte..mtime_low_end_byte].unpack('L>').first
        expect(mtime_high).to eq @lzop_test_fixture_file_data[mtime_high_start_byte..mtime_high_end_byte].unpack('L>').first

        mtime_fixed = ( mtime_high << 16 << 16 ) | mtime_low

        # puts "mtime_fixed: #{mtime_fixed}"
        # puts "mtime_fixed: #{mtime_fixed.to_s(16)}"

        expect(mtime_fixed).to eq @time_now.to_i

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @TrinitronX. BTW, you should check out the timecop gem. I suspect it will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a particular method to behave a certain way for your entire test suite, there's no reason to even deal with RSpec's stubs.  Instead, you can simply (re)define the method to behave how you want in your test environment:

```
class MyModel
  def my_method
    false
  end
end
```

This could go in `spec/spec_helper.rb` or a similar file.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach if you need to stub method chains:

allow_any_instance_of(Selenium::WebDriver::Driver).to(receive_message_chain('manage.window.resize_to').and_return(true))

Comment: This feels rude and crude...but it's the one thing that worked for me in my situation. Thanks, Myron Marston.

Answer (score 2):

What version of RSpec are you using? I believe `allow_any_instance_of` was introduced in RSpec 2.14. For earlier versions, you can use:

```
MyModel.any_instance.stub(:my_method).and_return(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following to stub a method 'do_this' of class 'Xyz' :

```
allow_any_instance_of(Xyz).to receive(:do_this).and_return(:this_is_your_stubbed_output)
```

This stubs the output to - ':this_is_your_stubbed_output' from wherever this function is invoked.

You may use the above piece of code in before(:each) block to make this applicable for all your spec examples.