# How to stub a third party object using rspec-mock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mailchimp, rspec-mocks

I'm kinda new to `rspec-mock`, now I'm integrating [hominid](https://github.com/tatemae-consultancy/hominid) to communicate with Mailchimp, I want to stub some method calls, so my request doesn't actually go to Mailchimp. Here is what I'm doing

**config/initilizers/mailchimp.rb**

```
MAILCHIMP = Hominid::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
LIST_ID   = ENV['MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID']
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_subscription
  private
    def add_subscription
      MAILCHIMP.list_subscribe(LIST_ID, .......) # Some params following
    end
end
```

So as you see, for every user created, a `list_subscribe` will be call on `MAILCHIMP`, now I don't want `list_subscribe` was actually called in every test because `User` was used everywhere, so I config globally a stub like this:

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    allow_any_instance_of(Hominid::API).to receive(:list_subscribe).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

I expected `MAILCHIMP` instance doesn't call `list_subscribe` but just return `true`, because if `list_subscribe` was called, some unexpected requests will go to Mailchimp, I want to prevent this. But my above code doesn't work, what I'm wrong? How to fix this?

Moreover, an answer is likely similar to my case here [How should I stub a method globally using RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218290/how-should-i-stub-a-method-globally-using-rspec)

I appreciate any help & suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've included within `config.before(:each) do` will execute before each test - no sooner. However, your initializer's code will execute once, before any of the test cases are executed.

This means that instance of `Hominid::API` stored in `MAILCHIMP` wasn't affected by the instruction to stub `Hominid::API.new` - it's still fully functional.

You should place the stub on `MAILCHIMP` as well:

```ruby
config.before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(Hominid::API).to receive(:list_subscribe).and_return(true)
  allow(MAILCHIMP).to receive(:list_subscribe).and_return(true)
end
```